# Grails. Domain class. Json string problem

Tags: json, grails, grails-orm

i have this domain class:

```
package test

class Credit {


    String office;
    String branch;
    String name;
    Integer code;
    Integer number;
    Integer term;
    Integer amount;
    Integer rate;


    static hasMany = [  debts : Debt, 
                fronts : Front,
                securities : Security,
                lawyers : Lawyer,
                guarantes : Guarante]


    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I need to create a string JSON, which contains only information about these fields:

```
String office;
        String branch;
        String name;
        Integer code;
        Integer number;
        Integer term;
        Integer amount;
        Integer rate;
```

I try:

```
rezult = Credit.list(fetch:[debts:"lazy", fronts: 'lazy', securities: "lazy", lawyers:"lazy", quarantes:"lazy"])
render new JSON(success: true, message: 'ok', data:rezult);
```

but in JSON string i have all data :( debts, fronts, securities... inside string too.
but i not need this data.

How I do avoid using them?

**ANSWER:**

```
render(contentType:"text/json") {
    success=true
    message='ok'
    totalCount=Credit.count()
    data = array {
        for(d in results) {
            data    office:d.office,
                    branch:d.branch, 
                    name: d.name,
                    code:d.code, 
                    number:d.number,
                    term:d.term,
                    amount:d.amount,
                    rate:d.rate
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and set `setRenderDomainClassRelations` on `JSON` to false but I suppose what you really need is to use a builder and explicitly declare the JSON structure further:

```
render(builder:'json') {
  success(true)
  message('ok')
  data {
    office(rezult.office)
    branch(rezult.branch)
    // and so on
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are going to have to use the json builder to solve this problem

[sample from a blog](http://shineycode.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/not-so-groovy-json/)

[Grails JSON Builder Documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1.x/api/grails/converters/JSON.Builder.html)